# How do I change the metadata items which scroll when playing mp3s in Windows Media Player without losing any of the track's information?

Tags: mp3, metadata

I would like to show the following metadata items "Title", "Year" and "Contributing artists" in that sequence, not "Title", "Contributing artists" and "Album" as shown at present.

Comment: Use any ID3 tag editor.